# how can I set file to input file from server URL

Tags: html, input

I have created a profile and saved it in the database with the company picture of the peson added .
My question here how can i clone this profile to create another one . for the `<input type="text">`  it's so easy but i have to clone also the company picture . how can i set to the `<input type="file">`  the path of the image on the server .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot programatically set the value of a text field , that would be a risk because you could upload any file from the client. Please see [How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)

Comment: Can i even set a relative path of the file or ,loag it from an <img src=""> thtml tag .